# Can't scroll through the items in Ionic 3 using *ngFor

Tags: html, ionic-framework, ionic3, ngfor

I am using *ngFor="let item of cartItems;  let i = index;" to inflate the list of items in the cart on my cart html page. What is happening is even if the cart items is more than 5-6, when the cart page is opened for the first time, only 2 items are displayed and somehow I am not able to scroll. When I click on the proceed button (present inside the footer element of the page) it takes me to the next page that is "Address form" and when I navigate back to the cart page again, I can scroll through the items. I don't know why is this happening that on the first load I am not able to scroll through the list. 
I have used *ngFor in a lot of places and never faced such a behavior.

This is my cart.html file

```
<ion-card class="style-this-card">
<div>
  <ion-list no-lines>
    <div>
    <ion-item no-lines *ngFor="let item of cartItems;  let i = index;">
      <ion-thumbnail item-start>
        <img style="width:100px; height:100px" [src]='item.Meal.r_image'>
      </ion-thumbnail>
      <p style="color:firebrick; font-weight:bold;"> {{item.Meal.price | currency:'INR':"symbol"}}</p>
      <p style="white-space:normal; font-weight:bold">{{item.Meal.name}}</p>
      <!-- <p style="font-size:12px; white-space:normal">{{item.Meal.mealDes}}</p> -->
      <p style="font-size:12px; white-space:normal">Edit quantity</p>
      <ion-grid class="no-padding-no-margin">
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col class="no-padding-no-margin">
            <button ion-button clear (click)="decreaseQty(item)">
              <ion-icon name="remove"></ion-icon>
            </button>
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col class="no-padding-no-margin">
            <p class="qty">{{item.qty}}</p>
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col class="no-padding-no-margin">
            <button ion-button clear (click)="increaseQty(item)">
              <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
            </button>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-grid>
      <ion-icon end name="trash" clear item-end (click)="remove(item.Meal, i )"></ion-icon>
    </ion-item>
  </div>
  </ion-list>
</div>
```

This is my footer which is visible only when there are items present inside the cart

```
<ion-footer *ngIf='!noItems'>
```

```
<ion-item-group>
  <ion-item-divider light text-left>Order Summary</ion-item-divider>
</ion-item-group>


<div>
  <ion-grid style="margin-top: 5px; padding-left: 0px;">
    <ion-row no-lines>
      <ion-col no-lines style="align-items: center; display: flex; padding-left: 0px; margin-left: 0px;">
        <ion-item style="margin: 0px;">
          <ion-input placeholder="Coupon" [(ngModel)]="coupon"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col no-lines style="align-items: center; display: flex">
        <ion-spinner *ngIf='isLoading'></ion-spinner>
        <div [hidden]='isLoading'>
          <button *ngIf='!isCouponValid' ion-button (click)="verify(coupon)">Apply</button>
          <button *ngIf='isCouponValid' ion-button clear (click)="removeCoupon()">
            <ion-icon name="md-close"></ion-icon>
          </button>
        </div>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</div>


<ion-grid no-padding>
  <ion-row no-padding>
    <ion-col>
      <div no-padding id="block1" style="padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px">
        <p style="font-size:14px; padding-top: 0px;">Sub Total</p>
      </div>
      <div no-padding id="block2" style="padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px">
        <p style="font-size:14px; padding-top: 0px;">{{ total | currency:'INR':"symbol"}}</p>
      </div>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>

  <ion-row *ngIf='isApplyCoupon'>
    <ion-col>
      <div no-padding id="block1" style="padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px">
        <p style="font-size:14px; padding-top: 0px; margin: 0px;">Coupon Applied</p>
      </div>
      <div no-padding id="block2" style="padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px">
        <p style="font-size:14px; padding-top: 0px; margin: 0px;">{{ - discountAmt | currency:'INR':"symbol"}}</p>
      </div>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>



  <ion-row no-padding>
    <ion-col *ngIf='isApplyCoupon'>
      <div no-padding id="block1" style="padding-top: 0px">
        <p style="font-size:16px; padding-top: 0px;">Total</p>
      </div>
      <div no-padding id="block2" style="padding-top: 0px">
        <p style="font-size:16px; padding-top: 0px;">{{ finalDiscAmnt | currency:'INR':"symbol"}}</p>
      </div>
    </ion-col>

    <ion-col *ngIf='!isApplyCoupon'>
      <div no-padding id="block1" style="padding-top: 0px">
        <p style="font-size:16px; padding-top: 0px;">Total</p>
      </div>
      <div no-padding id="block2" style="padding-top: 0px">
        <p style="font-size:16px; padding-top: 0px;">{{ total | currency:'INR':"symbol"}}</p>
      </div>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>

<button [hidden]='noItems' ion-button full color="primaryTwo" (click)="goToShipping()">CHECKOUT</button>
```

This is my cart.ts file. In my constructor, I am getting all the items inside of my cart

```
this.storage.ready().then(() => {
  this.storage.get("cart").then((data) => {
    if (data != null) {
      this.cartItems = data;
      console.log('cart items', this.cartItems);
      // console.log("cart data FOR UTKARSH", JSON.stringify(data));

      if (this.cartItems.length == 0 || this.cartItems == null) {
        this.noItems = true;
        console.log("no items here", this.noItems);
      } else {
        this.noItems = false;
        this.cartItems.forEach((item, index) => {
          // console.log("cartItems", this.cartItems[index].qty);
          // console.log("the contents of item", item);
          this.total = this.total + (item.Meal.price * item.qty)
          this.finalDiscAmnt = this.total;
          //console.log('The QTY is', item.qty);
          //console.log("cart data 2", this.cartItems);
          //this.displayPrice= this.displayPrice= item.product.produtPrice * item.qty;
          //console.log("prices are ", this.displayPrice= item.product.produtPrice * item.qty);
        });
      }
    }
  });
}).catch((err) => {
  this.noItems = true;
  console.log(err);
  this.cartItems = []
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by adding `@ViewChild(Content) content: Content` to my cart.ts file and 
using

```
setTimeout(() => {
      this.content.resize();
    }, 500);
```

inside of my constructor.

What this basically does is - tells the content to recalculate its dimensions. This should be called after dynamically adding/removing headers, footers, or tabs.

Since I was dynamically hiding my footer, this solved my issue.